# How to join 4 tables based on PK column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

In my stored procedure I have four select queries. These queries have a single column `JobDescriptionCode` common in them. I want to join these tables on that column.

This is my stored procedure :

```
SELECT a.JobDescriptionCode, ISNULL(a.ApprovedCount,0) -  ISNULL(b.ApprovedCount,0) AS StructureChange
FROM
(select rh.JobDescriptionCode, SUM(ApprovedCount) as ApprovedCount from RequisitionHistory rh 
left join OGJobDescription jd on rh.JobDescriptionCode = jd.JobDescriptionCode
where Convert(varchar(8),rh.CreationDate,1) between @PreviousMonthStartDate and @PreviousMonthEndDate
GROUP by rh.JobDescriptionCode) a
INNER JOIN
(select rh.JobDescriptionCode, SUM(ApprovedCount) as ApprovedCount from RequisitionHistory rh 
left join OGJobDescription jd on rh.JobDescriptionCode = jd.JobDescriptionCode
where Convert(varchar(8),rh.CreationDate,1) between @startDate and @endDate
GROUP by rh.JobDescriptionCode) b
on a.JobDescriptionCode = b.JobDescriptionCode

select r.JobDescriptionCode, count(*) as NewJoining from CandidateHistory ch 
left join Requisition r on ch.RequisitionCode = r.RequisitionCode
where ch.StatusCode = 6005 and Convert(varchar(8),ch.CreationDate,1) between @startDate and @endDate
GROUP BY r.JobDescriptionCode

select r.JobDescriptionCode, count(*) as Separation from CandidateHistory ch 
left join Requisition r on ch.RequisitionCode = r.RequisitionCode
where ch.StatusCode = 10005 and Convert(varchar(8),ch.CreationDate,1) between @startDate and @endDate
GROUP BY r.JobDescriptionCode

SELECT r.JobDescriptionCode, d.DepartmentName,jd.JobDescriptionName, SUM(r.ApprovedCount) as ApprovedCount, SUM(r.FilledCount) as FilledCount,
SUM(r.UnfilledCount) as UnfilledCount  from Requisition r
left join OGJobDescription jd on r.JobDescriptionCode = jd.JobDescriptionCode
left join OGDepartment d on r.DepartmentCode = d.DepartmentCode
where Convert(varchar(8),r.RequisitionDate,1) between @startDate and @endDate
GROUP BY jd.JobDescriptionName, d.DepartmentName, r.JobDescriptionCode
```

Now dates are passed as a parameter to the SP and are based on 1 month. Now some queries return 2 rows, some 10 and so on. I just want to match the PK `JobDescriptionCode` and on that, join the tables.

Is it possible, if so how?

Comment: What do you want your single table to contain?

Comment: All the values being returned such as  : JobDescriptionCode, 
    StructureChange,
    NewJoining,
    Separation,
    DepartmentName,
    JobDescriptionName,
    ApprovedCount,
    FilledCount,
    UnfilledCount

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can treat every separate query as a subquery and join them together like this:

```
SELECT q1.JobDescriptionCode, StructureChange, NewJoining, Separation, DepartmentName, JobDescriptionName, ApprovedCOUNT, FilledCOUNT, UnfilledCOUNT  
FROM (
    SELECT 
        a.JobDescriptionCode, 
        ISNULL(a.ApprovedCOUNT,0) - ISNULL(b.ApprovedCOUNT,0) AS StructureChange
    FROM (
        SELECT rh.JobDescriptionCode, SUM(ApprovedCOUNT) AS ApprovedCOUNT 
        FROM RequisitionHistory rh 
        LEFT JOIN OGJobDescription jd ON rh.JobDescriptionCode = jd.JobDescriptionCode
        WHERE CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),rh.CreationDate,1) BETWEEN @PreviousMonthStartDate AND @PreviousMonthEndDate
        GROUP BY rh.JobDescriptionCode
    ) a
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT rh.JobDescriptionCode, SUM(ApprovedCOUNT) AS ApprovedCOUNT 
        FROM RequisitionHistory rh 
        LEFT JOIN OGJobDescription jd ON rh.JobDescriptionCode = jd.JobDescriptionCode
        WHERE CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),rh.CreationDate,1) BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate
        GROUP BY rh.JobDescriptionCode
    ) b ON a.JobDescriptionCode = b.JobDescriptionCode
) q1

INNER JOIN (
    SELECT r.JobDescriptionCode, COUNT(*) AS NewJoining 
    FROM CANDidateHistory ch 
    LEFT JOIN Requisition r ON ch.RequisitionCode = r.RequisitionCode
    WHERE ch.StatusCode = 6005 AND CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),ch.CreationDate,1) BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate
    GROUP BY r.JobDescriptionCode
) q2 ON q1.JobDescriptionCode = q2.JobDescriptionCode

INNER JOIN (
    SELECT r.JobDescriptionCode, COUNT(*) AS Separation 
    FROM CANDidateHistory ch 
    LEFT JOIN Requisition r ON ch.RequisitionCode = r.RequisitionCode
    WHERE ch.StatusCode = 10005 AND CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),ch.CreationDate,1) BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate
    GROUP BY r.JobDescriptionCode
) q3 ON q1.JobDescriptionCode = q3.JobDescriptionCode

INNER JOIN (
    SELECT 
        r.JobDescriptionCode, 
        d.DepartmentName,
        jd.JobDescriptionName, 
        SUM(r.ApprovedCOUNT) AS ApprovedCOUNT, 
        SUM(r.FilledCOUNT) AS FilledCOUNT, 
        SUM(r.UnfilledCOUNT) AS UnfilledCOUNT  
    FROM Requisition r
    LEFT JOIN OGJobDescription jd ON r.JobDescriptionCode = jd.JobDescriptionCode
    LEFT JOIN OGDepartment d ON r.DepartmentCode = d.DepartmentCode
    WHERE CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),r.RequisitionDate,1) BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate
    GROUP BY jd.JobDescriptionName, d.DepartmentName, r.JobDescriptionCode
) q4 ON q1.JobDescriptionCode = q4.JobDescriptionCode
```

After looking a little at your queries I think it could be simplified a bit, will look a little more.

Edit: I think this query should be equivalent, but without test data it's a bit hard to confirm. If it produces the correct output it might perform better:

```
SELECT 
    q1.JobDescriptionCode, 
    q1.StructureChange, 
    q2.NewJoining, 
    q2.Separation, 
    q3.DepartmentName, 
    q3.JobDescriptionName, 
    q3.ApprovedCount, 
    q3.FilledCount, 
    q3.UnFilledCount  
FROM (
    SELECT rh.JobDescriptionCode, 
        SUM(CASE 
            WHEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),rh.CreationDate,1) BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate THEN -ApprovedCount 
            WHEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),rh.CreationDate,1) BETWEEN @PreviousMonthStartDate AND @PreviousMonthEndDate THEN ApprovedCount
        END) AS StructureChange 
    FROM RequisitionHistory rh 
    LEFT JOIN OGJobDescription jd ON rh.JobDescriptionCode = jd.JobDescriptionCode      
    GROUP BY rh.JobDescriptionCode
) q1
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT 
        r.JobDescriptionCode, 
        SUM(CASE WHEN ch.StatusCode = 6005 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS NewJoining,
        SUM(CASE WHEN ch.StatusCode = 10005 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Separation 
    FROM CandidateHistory ch 
    LEFT JOIN Requisition r ON ch.RequisitionCode = r.RequisitionCode
    WHERE CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),ch.CreationDate,1) BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate
    GROUP BY r.JobDescriptionCode
) q2 ON q1.JobDescriptionCode = q2.JobDescriptionCode
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT 
        r.JobDescriptionCode, 
        d.DepartmentName,
        jd.JobDescriptionName, 
        SUM(r.ApprovedCount) AS ApprovedCount, 
        SUM(r.FilledCount) AS FilledCount, 
        SUM(r.UnFilledCount) AS UnFilledCount  
    FROM Requisition r
    LEFT JOIN OGJobDescription jd ON r.JobDescriptionCode = jd.JobDescriptionCode
    LEFT JOIN OGDepartment d ON r.DepartmentCode = d.DepartmentCode
    WHERE CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),r.RequisitionDate,1) BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate
    GROUP BY jd.JobDescriptionName, d.DepartmentName, r.JobDescriptionCode
) q3 ON q1.JobDescriptionCode = q3.JobDescriptionCode
```

Comment: @NewbieProgrammer Happy to help. Did you have a chance to try the second version of the query? I'm just curious if it works and if so, if it performs better (which I think it will, maybe twice as fast).

Comment: Yes, I tried it and it works. But as my data is very limited, the performance factor is not visible. I only have 200-300 rows in the table :)

Answer (score 2):

Try putting all your queries into WITH like this:

```
WITH table_alias1 AS (
SELECT ...
),
table_alias2 AS (
SELECT .. ),
table_alias3 AS (
SELECT .. ),
table_alias4 AS (
SELECT .. )
SELECT * FROM 
 table_alias1 t1 INNER JOIN
 table_alias2 t2 ON t1.JobDescriptionCode = t2.JobDescriptionCode INNER JOIN
 table_alias2 t3 ON t1.JobDescriptionCode = t3.JobDescriptionCode INNER JOIN
 table_alias2 t4 ON t1.JobDescriptionCode = t4.JobDescriptionCode;
```

Your queries are massive, so I did not put them here for readability reasons.